# What’s the motivation for using Ricci scalar in action term for spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, action

Why do we use Ricci scalar in the action equation for the spacetime? Why don’t we use other functions? Is it just intuition? What forces us to use that?

Answer (score 4):

$R$ is the lowest-order (and thus simplest) scalar that can be formed from the Riemann curvature tensor. That plus a constant term (the cosmological constant) seem sufficient to explain what we observe. It is possible that the Lagrangian density is more complicated, but physicists choose the simplest explanation that works.

Some physicists think that when we have an accepted theory of quantum gravity, these two terms will turn out to be just the beginning of an expansion of the action in an infinite series of powers of the curvature. These higher-order terms will be significant only at the Planck scale.

Comment: Nice answer! Just one comment on "these two terms will turn out to be just the beginning of an expansion of the action in an infinite series of powers of the curvature": by naturalness argument, each coefficient of the said infinite series of powers of the curvature should be of order 1 in Planck units. Curiously, the zeroth term (cosmological constant term) has an unexpected small coefficient $10^{-120}$.